# Overleaf can't find upright font files in folders

Tags: fontspec

Overleaf renders a pdf properly when the upright font file is in the root folder, but returns an error when the file is in a folder.

Here's the source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  ItalicFont={fonts/LinLibertine_RIah.ttf},
  ]{LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}

\begin{document}

Hello \emph{world}

\end{document}
```

and here's the file structure.

[image]

but if I move the upright file into the same folder, changing the source thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  ItalicFont={fonts/LinLibertine_RIah.ttf},
  ]{fonts/LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}

\begin{document}

Hello \emph{world}

\end{document}
```

and updating the file structure

[image]

returns an error.

How do I move properly refer to the upright font file when its in a folder?

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf help desk about this issue?

Comment: i have not--i thought I was making some rudimentary TeX error

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf]_ Actually your code snippet doesn't work either when I tried compiling it on a local TeX Live installation, but using the `Path` option does: `\setmainfont[Path=fonts/,ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RIah.ttf]{LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}`

Comment: @LianTzeLim that fixed it--thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf]*

Actually your code snippet doesn't work either when I tried compiling it on a local TeX Live installation. But using the `Path` option does:

```
\setmainfont[Path=fonts/,
             ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RIah.ttf]
  {LinLibertine_Rah.ttf}
```